# tomcat session not serializable for spring component with @Value injection

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat, serialization

It's a rather strange problem. In Spring I've configured a bean as session.

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserSession implements Serializable{...}
```

There is an interceptor which who interact with this session.

```
public class UserInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    ...
    @Autowired private UserSession userSession;
    @Autowired private WebUser webUser;

    public boolean preHandle(...){
        userSession.setUserId(webUser.getUserId());
        userSession.setUserList(webUser.getUsers());
        ...
    }
...
}
```

The `WebUser` is an interface, in which depend on environment it will inject different `WebUser`. In profile `LOCAL`, in will inject `LocalWebUser`

```
@Component
@Primary
@Profile({"LOCAL"})
public class LocalWebUser implements WebUser, Serializable{
   @Autowired private transient UserManager userManager;

   @Value("${env.tester.userId}")
   private transient String userId;

   @Override
   public List<String> getUsers() {
       return this.userManager.getUsers();
   }
   ...
}
```

Notice that I did give make field as `transient` to prevent common serialization problem. However, in tomcat it throws that `LocalWebUser` is not serializable.

> > Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
> >          com.company.component.web.LocalWebUser$1
> >          at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
> >          at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
> >          at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
> >         ....

`LocalWebUser` is actually **not stored in session**, it's just that session retrieve value from it. Why it complains about it is not serializable?

I did found out a solution that by **removing `@Value` injection** from properties, the exception went away, which confuse me even more....

Answer (score 1):

It's not complaining about `LocalWebUser`. It's complaining about `LocalWebUser$1` which is an anonymous inner class within `LocalWebUser`. Look through the code in `LocalWebUser` for something like this:

```
Object something = new Something() { .... };
```

That's an anonymous inner class. If that isn't serializable and a reference to that is being leaked into an object stored in the session, then there's your problem.

Comment: wow. Good observation. There is some guava transformation at getUsers() which would `new Function()`, that might be the cause?

Comment: Perhaps. Are you able to see the resulting code anywhere, or does Guava compile to in-memory bytecode?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the @Value annotation modifies the type of the `userId` field to some other, non serializable type, through bytecode manipulation.

So when you call `userSession.setUserId(webUser.getUserId())` it copies that non serializable type to the UserSession.

However I could not find any reference about the @Value annotation to support that, so this is just a hunch.

You could probably validate this by inspecting the type of the `userId` field at runtime with a debugger.